# How to reset StringVar in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on a calculator and I was coding the C Button (C button is the button which erases the current operation) however, My idea was to make the C Button return all Variables used during the operation to their starting state so we can start a new operation after pressing C. The problem is there is something called StringVar() in Tkinter that I used after reading an answer on StackOverflow. It is used to update the label every time I hit a new Button. it works but when trying to return it to its normal state when pressing the C button it doesn't work. They are still the same. so how can I reset the StringVar?

solution: Turns out I didn't assign the global variables used in the function, but any way to reset the stringVar you can just do this : `(variable name).set("")`

Comment: What exactly have you tried to clear it?

Comment: I tried (variable name).set("") and also (variable name) = tk.StringVar() but nothing worked

Comment: `variable_name.set("")` is how you do it. If it didn't work for you, [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I will work on it

Comment: I did it and edited my post

Comment: Those first four statements in `buttonC()` are pointless; they're setting *local variables* (that vanish when the function ends), unrelated to the global variables with the same names.

Comment: my bad, what a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `variableName.set("")`

```
s = StringVar()

# here getting textvariable

value = s.get()
print(value)  # input value

s.set("")  # reset it
```

---

Edit: After below comment, I am adding this structure to show how to keep desired item clean

```
# getting input
sFaculty = StringVar()
combo = ttk.Combobox(tab1, ..., textvariable=sFaculty, ...)

# assing it to function
Button(tab1, text="Insert", command=lambda: guiActions.insertStudent(..., sFaculty, ...))

# process and clean in a function
def insertStudent(..., faculty, ...):

    # process here

    # cleaning after insert
    faculty.set("")
```

Comment: I tried this, It clears the label but after typing another number it gets back the old number and puts the another number beside it. what makes me think it is the problem is that the debugger shows it doesn't do anything

Comment: I will edit my answer and give an example to show how I used it once. Because I have used it in a repetitive way and it was consistent.

Comment: maybe the problem is in another part of my code then. but I don't know why my debugger is showing it did nothing. Thanks for the answer

Comment: my problem was in global variables. I forgot to put them in the function so the function created local variables.